# android:exported in flutter old project

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I ran an old Flutter project but I got the following errors:

```
\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:35:9-41:19 Error:
    android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <service#com.adpdigital.push.location.LocationService>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.
```

I updated all dependencies.

`
http: ^0.13.5
provider: ^6.0.5
photo_view: ^0.14.0
intl: ^0.18.1
flutter_rating_bar: ^4.0.1
shared_preferences: ^2.1.0
uni_links: ^0.5.1
encrypt: ^5.0.1
url_launcher: ^6.1.10
auto_size_text: ^3.0.0
flutter_datetime_picker: ^1.5.1
package_info_plus: ^3.1.2
video_player: ^2.6.1
cached_network_image: ^3.2.3
location_picker_web:
path: ./location_picker_web
pointer_interceptor: ^0.9.3+4

location: ^4.4.0
`

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="_______________">
    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <!--
    Google play rejects it. Need to use sms retrieve api
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    -->

    <!--    TODO remove cleartext traffic allow (it was for testing category webView)-->
    <application
        android:name="cpkg.App"
        android:label="____"
        android:exported="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">

        <activity
            android:name="cpkg.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>


            <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver"
                android:exported="false">
            </receiver>


            <!-- Deep Links -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with nwshop9821://shop.host -->
                <data
                    android:scheme="__**__" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- App Links -->
<!--            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">-->
<!--                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />-->
<!--                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />-->
<!--                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />-->
<!--                &lt;!&ndash; Accepts URIs that begin with https://YOUR_HOST &ndash;&gt;-->
<!--                <data-->
<!--                    android:scheme="https"-->
<!--                    android:host="[YOUR_HOST]" />-->
<!--            </intent-filter>-->


            <!-- Firebase messaging. on click notification  -  update:removed as not required anymore-->
<!--            <intent-filter>-->
<!--                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />-->
<!--                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />-->
<!--            </intent-filter>-->

        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />





<!--        CHABOK START-->

<!--        CHABOK NOTIFICATION ICON-->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.adpdigital.push.client.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_baseline_my_location_24" />
        <!-- Set color used with incoming notification messages. This is used when no color is set for the incoming
     notification message. See README(http : oo.gl/6BKBk7) for more. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/notification_color" />


        <!--        CHABOK Third-Party App Stores tracker-->
<!--        <receiver-->
<!--            android:name="com.adpdigital.push.ChabokReferrerReceiver"-->
<!--            android:permission="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"-->
<!--            android:exported="true">-->
<!--            <intent-filter>-->
<!--                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />-->
<!--            </intent-filter>-->
<!--        </receiver>-->

        <!--        FIREBASE MESSAGE SERVICE. TO IMPLEMENT DART BACKGROUND NOTIFICATION-->
        <service
            android:name="cpkg.tracker.ImplFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

<!--        CHABOK END-->






        <!--
        <receiver android:name="cpkg.sms_listener.SmsBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        -->



        <receiver android:name="cpkg.sms_listener.SmsRetrieveReceiver" android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.SMS_RETRIEVED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I added:
android:exported="true"

But I still have the first error.

I updated all dependencies.
I added:
android:exported="true"

Answer (score 1):

Add the below to your Android manifest.

```xml
<service android:name="com.adpdigital.push.location.LocationService"
android:exported="true">
```

Run the project and see if the issues persist.